# JUnit @ParametrizedTest Class Objects as Value Source?

Tags: java, junit

I would like to create a ParametrizedTest that tests a bunch of different AIs at the same time, making sure that the don't take too long to do their calculations. However, I cannot create new Objects in the ValueSource, so I'm unsure how to proceed.

The problem is that I need to pass constant values to ValueSource, which is where I get stuck. **How can I make my objects constant?**

```
 @ParameterizedTest
  @ValueSource(ais = {new AdvancedAI(), new blabla})
  public void moveCalculatedInTimeBy(AI TestAI) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Turn turn = Turn.initialTurn();
    Move calculatedMove = TestAI.calculateMove(Optional.empty(), turn);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    assertTrue(endTime <= 8000);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `@ValueSource` is for simple arguments, the kind that can be set as values to annotation elements. In other words, primitives, strings, and classes<sup>1</sup>. Since you want to provide *instances* of a class this won't work for you. Instead, you'll want to use something like [`@MethodSource`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.params/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/MethodSource.html)<sup>2</sup>.

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("testAiProvider")
void moveCalculatedInTimeBy(AI testAI) {
  // perform test...
}

static List<AI> testAiProvider() {
  // return List of test AI instances
}
```

See the [user guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource) and Javadoc for more information, such as what return types are allowed for factory methods.

---

<sup>1. *Enum constants can also be used in annotations, but you can't make a generic enum annotation element. That's why JUnit 5 also has `@EnumSource`.*</sup>

<sup>2. *You can also use `@ArgumentsSource` directly, which lets you define an `ArgumentsProvider`, if you need it.*</sup>